# How to print out dictionary lists in new line without square brackets and apostrophes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How do I print out the dictionary lists like this?:

```
Tino Black
Alex Blue
Meow Red
Woof White
```

I want the left column to be the name and right column to be colours for each name.

Here are my codes:

```
ask = input("Name and colour: ")
colourList = {}

while ask:
  name, colour = ask.split()
  colourList[name] = colour
  ask = input("Name and colour: ")

print(colourList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, for example:

```
for name, color in colourList.items(): # this is actually a colourDictionary
    print(name, color)
```